# Повысить быстродействие

Tags: python

В каком участке кода, по Вашему мнению можно повысить быстродействие?

Доступ к базе не учитывать, число записей примерно 17К.

```
 tstart = datetime.now()
 X = '([a-f0-9]{2}[:]?){6}'
 p = {}
 res = engine.execute("SELECT ;").fetchall()
 for k,v in res:
     a = re.compile(X).search(k)
     if a:
        p.update({k:v})
 tend = datetime.now()
 print("Speed: %s!!!!!!" %(tend - tstart))

 Speed: 0:00:00.262114
```

Answer (score 5):

```
res = engine.execute("SELECT ;").fetchall()
pattern = re.compile('([a-f0-9]{2}[:]?){6}')
p = dict(filter(lambda x: pattern.search(x[0]), res))
```

Comment: Еще один вопрос...


    rip = p.get('DHCP-Requested-IP-Address', None) if p.get('DHCP- Requested-IP-Address', None) != '0.0.0.0' else None


Увеличить можно быстродействия?

Comment: Зачем этот двойной вызов функции, когда можно просто сделать:  

    a= b()
    if a!=...: a=c